# How can I measure the current and voltage of each source in a DC circuit with multiple sources?

Tags: raspberry-pi, current-measurement, current-source, voltage-measurement, shunt

In my off grid house I have a hydro-electric turbine and two separate solar arrays, each producing power at between 0 and 14.7 volts; nominally 12. The amperage varies, but the while system can peak at 50A on a clear day.

These sources are brought together so as to be in parallel through a main disconnect, at which point they are also in parallel with my AC inverter/charger and battery bank; there is a load-diverter that works with the inverter/charger to manage the batteries. Each has their own disconnect and fusing as appropriate.

I want to create a pretty comprehensive metering system using resistive shunts and [Yoctopuce miliVoltRx](http://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/products/usb-electrical-sensors/yocto-millivolt-rx) units (posting to a RPi) that can measure and record current and voltage for *each* power source, as well and the battery bank. This is within the capability of the devices.

**My Question is: because the DC system forms "one circuit", is it even possible to directly measure the sources; shunts are usually placed on the (-) side, does that isolate them at all? What does this look like? How can I do it?**

I'm writing the software for the Yocotopuces myself, so if there is calculation combined with measurement necessary, that will be possible for me top implement. But designing that is beyond my layman's reckoning.

Sorry for not having a schematic. If it's necessary to understand the problem I can sketch something up.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: well, the ethernet port on the raspberry pi is isolated (if you use an ordinary unshielded ethernet cable), so if you need to make isolated measurements one option is to put a raspberry pi at each location

Comment: Thanks for the response Jasen. This is what I was thinking too, however, since the DC system forms one circuit, I'm pretty sure multiple meters would just read the same values, since there is no resistance between them and the voltage averages. I'm looking for some engineered solution which could offset this ... or an explanation that I'm wrong.

Comment: with the two sources connected in parrallel both will produce the same voltage, they may produce different currents.   yoctowatt is probably better suited to this application, but you;ll miss all the fun of thermai EMF messing up your current measurments etc...

Comment: none of the yocto sensors has the capacity to measure my system directly, the amperages are too high, which is what brought me to the shunt. Thanks though

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the yocto millivolt rx has an isolated input so there's no worries that it could mix your measurement results up. each yoctopuce will only see the voltage due to the current in the connected shunt.

[image: schematic]

for best results use a kelvin connection, connecting the youcopuce inputs doirectly to the shunts.  there's no need to connect the shuts in the negative side, but if that's most convenient do it that way.

Comment: This isn't terribly helpful to me, but your schematic captures the correct answer that I found elsewhere, so I'll mark it correct for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this. If your DC bus voltage remains constant then this is just a matter of measuring your DC current in each branch and multiplying by the voltage if you want to calculate power.

[image]

*Figure 1. A 5-channel AC/DC current sensor board.*

A quick web search for DC current sensors throws up many results such as that of Figure 1. Generally these devices use Hall effect sensors embedded in a slot of a torroidal core. The Hall sensor measures the magnetic flux in the core and responds to DC as well as AC (whereas a regular current transformer is AC only).

Linear make a range of high-side current monitoring devices if you wish to roll your own.

[image]

*Figure 2. [Linear LTC4151](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC4151). 0.02 Ω is probably for a high current.*

This particular one seems to use serial transmission. Analog versions are available too.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! As I pointed out though, the goal is to use the Yoctopuce USB device and a shunt to do the measurement so that it can be logged. The device you suggested is not compatible with this outcome. Moreover, the voltage is not constant: variable light levels on the solar arrays and the multiple phases of the battery charge cycle mean that the voltage of the system fluctuates quite a bit.